# Markov process with time varying transition kernels

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I cross post this question from StackExchange as it may be more appropriate.

I am interested in studying the evolution of a variable $\alpha_t\in [0,1]$ governed by the following stochastic dynamical system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha_0\in [0,1]\\ 
\alpha_{t+1}=\frac{t+1}{t+2}\alpha_{t} + \frac{1}{t+2}W_t\\
W_t\sim Bernoulli(P(\alpha_{t})) 
\end{cases}
$$
where $P:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a continuous decreasing function such that $P(0.5)=0.5$ and there exist $0<a<1/2<b<1$ such that $P(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,a]$ and  $P(x)=0$ for $x\in [b,1]$.

A qualitative study of the system should reveal that $\alpha_t$ will be eventually bound in $[a,b]$. My idea is as follows. Consider any time $\tau$ when $\alpha_\tau<a$, one will transition inside the interval again in $\lceil{\frac{1}{1-a}(\tau+1)(a-\alpha_\tau)}\rceil$  steps. Consider any time $\tau$ when $\alpha_\tau>b$, one will transition inside the interval again in $\lceil{\frac{1}{b}(\tau+1)(\alpha_\tau-b)}\rceil$  steps. Hence, for any $\tau$ we can always find $\tau'>\tau$ such that $\alpha_{\tau'}\in [a,b]$. Starting from $\alpha_{\tau'}\in [a,b]$ one can oscillate in between $\left[\frac{\tau'+1}{\tau'+2}a, \frac{\tau'+1}{\tau'+2}b+\frac{1}{\tau'+2}\right]$. Hence, as $\tau$ and $\tau'$ go to infinity, one gets the result.

At the same time, I would like to have a more precise prediction about the asymptotic behavior of $\alpha_t$. Running all sorts of simulation, one has that asymptotically
$$\alpha_t\to 1/2$$
This is somewhat intuitive because, for a very large $T$ we have $\frac{T+1}{T+2}\approx 1$ and $\frac{1}{T}\approx 0$ and $P(1/2)=1/2$. Hence, the system moves with equal probability infinitesimally to the left or infinitesimally to the right.

My limited knowledge of stochastic dynamical systems prevents me from proving formally
$$\alpha_t\xrightarrow{prob.}1/2$$
I would like to know if there is a way.

My attempts so far are:

**a)** Observe that

$$\alpha_T=\frac{1}{T+1}\alpha_0+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}W_t}{T+1}$$

hence, for $T\to\infty$ the first term drops, while the second may be evaluated via a weak law of large numbers. The point is that, not only variables $W_t$ are all correlated, but also they are not identically distributed. Hence, I do not know any law of large numbers to apply here.

**b)** Try to study the evolution of $\alpha_t$ considering a Markov process on an extended state space, namely allowing the state to be $$(t,\alpha_t,w_t)\in\mathbb{N}\times[0,1]\times\{0,1\}$$
with transition specified by the following Markov kernel
$$(t,\alpha_t,w_t)\in\mathbb{N}\times[0,1]\times\{0,1\}\mapsto\delta_{t+1}\otimes \{P(\alpha_t)\delta_{\frac{(t+1)\alpha_t+1}{t+2}}+(1-P(\alpha_t))\delta_{\frac{(t+1)\alpha_t}{t+2}}\}\otimes \{P(\alpha_t)\delta_{1}+(1-P(\alpha_t))\delta_{0}\}\in\Delta(\mathbb{N}\times[0,1]\times\{0,1\})$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the independent product of measures. I don't really know how to study such a Markov process, as my knowledge is limited to simpler cases. In particular, beside the complicated state space, the point is that starting from the same $\alpha$ at two different times $t,t'$ the support of the probability distribution describing the transitions from this point is different from time $t$ to time $t'$.

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: "A qualitative study of the system reveals ..." Can you share details of that study?

Comment: when rewritten in the form $\alpha_{+1}=\alpha_+ \frac 1 {+2} (_ -  \alpha_t} $ where you are looking for the zero of the function $P(\alpha) - \alpha$.  Here is the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation

Comment: @mike I fear your comment shows up only in part in the box. But it looks very useful. Would you mind rewriting the first part ? (It looks there is something before when reweritten)

Comment: @mike I think your idea is to look at the recursion for alpha as the iterate of the Robbins Moro algorithm. The point is that then, in the wikipedia notation, I have to set $\alpha=1/2$ and define $N(\theta)=\theta-W+1/2$ whose expected value is $1/2+\theta-P(\theta)\neq P(\theta)$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I added my intuition for the qualitative study. I don't know if saying "eventually bounded" in $[a,b]$ is right, but I hope to have conveyed the idea.

Comment: when rewritten in the form $\alpha_{+1}=\alpha_+ \frac 1 {+2} (_ -  \alpha_t)$ where you are looking for the zero of the function $P(\alpha) - \alpha$.  Here is the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation...cleaned up version of previous, I had an extra bracket in the tex